# Closed form inverse for the matrix $\exp(-|m-n|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

In the context of physically coupled oscillators with short-range interactions, the following interaction potential appears:

$V(x_1,x_2) = e^{-a|x_1-x_2|}$

Here, $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $a>0$.

In calculating some of the physical properties of the system, the expression $$\left[\delta(x_1-x_2)-b V(x_1,x_2)\right]^{-1}$$ needs to be calculated, where $b\neq-1$. Here $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta distribution. This effectively requires knowledge of the functional inverse of $V$, or $V^{-1}(x_1,x_2)$

I have stepped back from this problem and attempted to first examine the presumably simpler case of a discretized system.

Now $x_1,x_2 \in \{-L,-L+1,...,L-1, L\}$. Then I have the square matrix $$V_{x_1,x_2} = e^{-a|x_1-x_2|}$$
Or perhaps more simply:
$$V_{m,n} = e^{-a|m-n|}$$

This matrix is real, positive-definite, symmetric, and Toeplitz so it is definitely invertible and seemingly very well-behaved. For large enough values of $a$ the matrix approaches the identity matrix exponentially fast.

The question I have is whether this special matrix has a closed form solution for its inverse. Or, at least, whether this special matrix has ever been studied in any detail. By eye, the matrix looks so symmetric I feel it must have appeared in another context.

Ex. For an 4x4 system

$$V=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  e^{-a}&  e^{-2a}& e^{-3a}\\ 
 e^{-a}&  1&  e^{-a}& e^{-2a}\\ 
 e^{-2a}&  e^{-a}&  1& e^{-a}\\ 
 e^{-3a}&  e^{-2a}&  e^{-a}& 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Edit: I attempted to invert the above matrix with Mathematica to get the following matrix.

$$V=\frac{-e^{a}}{1-e^{2a}}\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{a}&  -1&  0& 0\\ 
 -1&  e^{a}+e^{-a}&  -1& 0\\ 
 0&  -1&  e^{a}+e^{-a}& -1\\ 
 0&  0&  -1& e^{a}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\eta$ be the $n \times n$ matrices with superdiagonal entries $1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Let $\bar{\eta}$ be its transpose.

$$\eta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & j = i + 1\\0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad 
\bar{\eta}_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & j = i - 1\\0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
They are nilpotent matrices ($\eta^n = \bar{\eta}^n = 0$ ) and satisfy identities
$$\eta \bar{\eta} \eta = \eta \quad\text{ and }\quad\bar{\eta} \eta \bar{\eta} = \bar{\eta}\tag{*1}$$
It is easy to verify both $\bar{\eta}\eta$ and $\eta\bar{\eta}$ are diagonal matrices with all but one diagonal entries equal to $1$.
$\bar{\eta}\eta$ vanishes on the first diagonal entry while $\eta\bar{\eta}$ vanishes on the last diagonal entry.
$$(\bar{\eta}\eta)_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i = j > 1\\0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
(\eta\bar{\eta})_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i = j < n\\0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Let $\lambda = e^{-a}$. In terms of $\eta$ and $\bar{\eta}$, the matrix $V$ at hand can be rewritten as

$$V = I + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda^k \eta^k  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lambda^k \bar{\eta}^k
= I + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda^k \eta^k  + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^k \bar{\eta}^k
= (I - \lambda \eta)^{-1} + (I - \lambda\bar{\eta})^{-1}\lambda\bar{\eta}$$
Multiply $V$ by $(I - \lambda\bar{\eta})$ on the left and $(I-\lambda\eta)$ on the right, we get
$$(I - \lambda\bar{\eta})V(I-\lambda\eta) = (I - \lambda\bar{\eta}) + \lambda\bar{\eta}(I - \lambda\eta) = I - \lambda^2\bar{\eta}\eta\tag{*2}$$
The rightmost matrix is a diagonal matrix with $1$ at first
diagonal entry and $1 - \lambda^2$ at the rest of the diagonal.
When $\lambda^2 \ne 1$, it is invertible with inverse 
$$\left(I - \lambda^2 \bar{\eta}\eta\right)^{-1} = I + \frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}\bar{\eta}\eta\tag{*3}$$
Invert both sides of $(*2)$ and apply $(*1)$ and $(*3)$, we obtain

$$V^{-1} = ( 1 - \lambda\eta)\left( I + \frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}\bar{\eta}\eta \right)( 1 - \lambda \bar{\eta})
= I -\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2}(\eta + \bar{\eta}) + \frac{\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}\left(\bar{\eta}\eta + \eta\bar{\eta}\right)
$$
This means $V^{-1}$ is a tridiagonal matrix with 
$\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}$ at first and last diagonal entries,
$\frac{1+\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}$ at the remaining diagonal entries
and $-\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2}$ on the subdiagonals. i.e $V^{-1}$ has the form
$$
V^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\lambda & 0 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-\lambda & 1 + \lambda^2 & -\lambda & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\lambda & 1 + \lambda^2 & -\lambda & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -\lambda & 1+\lambda^2 & -\lambda & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -\lambda & 1+\lambda^2 & -\lambda\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & - \lambda & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Writing the matrix in terms of the nilpotent matricies (ladder operators) is very clever! It's almost like this matrix is made to be written in the way you did...Any comments on the generality of this approach?

Comment: @user157879 I don't believe this is general. However, for matrices whose entries depends only one $i-j$, this is a trick one should keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your computation for $V^{-1}$ already suggests that $V^{-1}$ behaves like a Laplacian on your discrete lattice. Let us check this by the following heuristic computation:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} V(x, y) &= -a\operatorname{sign}(x - y)V(x,y), \\
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} V(x, y) &= -2a\delta(x-y) + a^2V(x,y).
\end{align*}

This suggests that $ V^{-1} = \frac{1}{2a}\left( a^2 - \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \right)$. To make this argument a bit more rigorous, we investigate $V$ on the Fourier side. Notice first that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2 t^2} \, e^{2\pi i x t} \, dt = e^{-a|x|}. $$

Thus for $\varphi \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, Fubini's theorem tells that

\begin{align*}
V\varphi(x)
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V(x, y)\varphi(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2 t^2} \, e^{2\pi i (x-y) t}\varphi(y) \, dt \, dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{2a}{a^2+4\pi^2 t^2}}_{=:\hat{V}(t)} \, e^{2\pi i x t} \mathcal{F}\varphi(t) \, dt
 = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{V}(\mathcal{F}\varphi))(x)
\end{align*}

That is, $V$ is simply a multiplicative operator on the Fourier side. So its inverse is given by

$$ V^{-1}\varphi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a^2+4\pi^2 t^2}{2a} \, e^{2\pi i x t} \mathcal{F}\varphi(t) \, dt, $$

which we easily identify as the operator $\frac{1}{2a}\left(a^2 - \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)$ as claimed.

---

For the discrete case, Mathematica suggests that

$$ [V^{-1}]_{m,n} = \frac{1}{e^{a} - e^{-a}} \times \begin{cases}
e^a,         & i = j \in \{-L, L\} \\
e^a + e^{-a} & i = j \in \{-L+1, \cdots, L-1\} \\
-1           & |i - j| = 1 \\
0            & |i - j| \geq 2
\end{cases} $$

which I have no simple idea to prove at this point. Notice that this guess is again consistent with our previous computation in the following sense: Consider the operator $V(x,y)$ on the rescaled lattice $\{ -L\delta, \cdots, L\delta \}$, then with a nice function $\varphi$, we have

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n} [V^{-1}]_{m \delta, n \delta} \cdot \varphi(n \delta) \\
&\hspace{2em} = \frac{1}{\delta\sinh(a\delta)}\left( \cosh(a\delta)\varphi(mx) - \frac{\varphi((m-1)\delta) + \varphi((m+1)\delta)}{2} \right) \\
&\hspace{4em} \xrightarrow[\quad \substack{m\delta &\to x \\ \delta &\to 0} \quad]{} \frac{1}{2a}(a^2\varphi(x) - \varphi''(x)).
\end{align*}

Comment: Great insight in seeing the function is Laplace-like (though I guess for the equation $\nabla^2+a^{-2}=0$). In retrospect, after seeing it was Toeplitz and its analytic inverse for the finite case this should have been clear.